# Improving the performance of read()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, io

I'm trying to write a proxy-application for Android.
I created a ServerSocket that listens on the localhost and a port. 
When a browser requests a site, I open a new thread with the Socket and read the inputstream.

The problem: The read-call is too slow. It needs up to one second.
I don't think the browser's outputstream is that slow.

```
public Request readRequest() {
    int length;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

    long startTime = System.nanoTime(); // Messure starts
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != 0) {
        Log.d("PERFORMANCE", "read() needs " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime)/1000000 + " ms for: " + length + " bytes"); // Messure ends

        Request request = Request.parse(buffer, length);
        if (request != null) {
            // read bytes contained a complete Request
            return request;
        }

        // request is incomplete -> read more        
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I thought it might could be a sheduling problem, so i already tried to increase the priority of the current Thread. It slightly improved the speed.

Is there another way to decrease the idle time or latency?
What about NDK/JNI?

Comment: Use `>= 0'  as -1 is possible too. You mention all the right keywords, so I hesitate to mention that the code problem may lay elsewhere, InputStreamBuffer, at the server OutputStreamBuffer.

Comment: Can we have a look at your  if (request != null) ?

Comment: It is recommended to use classes like ByteBuffer etc. which is NIO like recommendation for android. Check it out.Graphics libraries use the same to communicate with native and java

Answer (score 0):

First thing I want to give a note:

```
int length;
```

should be IMO:

```
long length = 0L;
```

Solution for your problem could be increasing the buffer size for `byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];`

Also maybe `Request request = Request.parse(buffer, length);` could be slowing down everything.